# Flutter how to add border to C2ChipStyle

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to add a border to a C2ChipStyle.filled but it doesn't work. It looks like this:
[image]

I want to add a black border to the blue 'L'. Does anyone know how to solve it?

Here is the code I am using:

```
return C2ChipStyle.filled(
padding: const EdgeInsets.all(4),
color: const Color.fromARGB(255, 220, 233, 255),
borderWidth: 3,
borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(25)),
borderOpacity: 1,
);
```